# Setting variables which is not entered in GUI and "Not Responding" Problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui, pysimplegui

I wanted to write a program that moves the mouse cursor and presses the shift key so that the computer won't be locked. The Problem is I want that if the user doesn't set two variables they should be automatically 0 and 1 but it seems I am missing something. The other thing that I can't understand is when I start the program if I don't click on it everything is ok, but if I click on the program's window it says "Not Responding" but the program is running. I can't understand what I am doing wrong here. Below is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pyautogui
import time
import sys
import os
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from datetime import datetime

def main():
    sg.theme('DarkAmber')
    layout = [  [sg.Text('Please enter the time intervall between the movements:', size = (45,1)), sg.Input(key='-IT-', enable_events=True)],
                [sg.Text('Please enter how long should the script run:', size = (45,1)), sg.Input(key='-DURATION-', enable_events=True)],
                [sg.Button('Start'), sg.Button('Stop')],
                [sg.Output(size=(60,15))]   ]
    window = sg.Window('Press to start to move!', layout, size=(450,250), element_justification='right')
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Stop'):         
            break
        
        if event == '-IT-' and values['-IT-'] and values['-IT-'][-1] not in ('0123456789'):
            window['-IT-'].update(values['-IT-'][:-1])
        if event == '-DURATION-' and values['-DURATION-'] and values['-DURATION-'][-1] not in ('0123456789'):
            window['-DURATION-'].update(values['-DURATION-'][:-1])
        
        elif event == 'Start':
            if values['-IT-'] == "" and values['-DURATION-'] == "":
                window['-IT-'].update(1)
                window['-DURATION-'].update(0)
            elif values['-IT-'] != "" and values['-DURATION-'] == "":
                window['-DURATION-'].update(0)
            elif values['-IT-'] == "" and values['-DURATION-'] != "":
                window['-IT-'].update(1)    
            move(numMin=int('0'+values['-IT-']), numDuration=int('0'+values['-DURATION-']))
    window.close()
main()
```

Edit:
I've just cut out the unnecessary part of the code.
So if I'm not misunderstanding, I need to use a thread, the second question is for me unclear can I typecast an empty string without adding zero (0) to it? Because when I try just typecast it doesn't work, and if I add a zero the behavior of the code is changing.

Comment: "Not responding" is usually an indication that something in your event loop is taking a long time. I would look at whether your `while` loops are getting stuck in an endless or very complex loop. Please _add debugging efforts_ and try to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

### Operations That Take a "Long Time"

If you're a Windows user you've seen windows show in their title bar "Not Responding" which is soon followed by a Windows popup stating that "Your program has stopped responding". Well, you too can make that message and popup appear if you so wish! All you need to do is execute an operation that takes "too long" (i.e. a few seconds) inside your event loop.

You have a couple of options for dealing this with. If your operation can be broken up into smaller parts, then you can call Window.Refresh() occasionally to avoid this message. If you're running a loop for example, drop that call in with your other work. This will keep the GUI happy and Window's won't complain.

If, on the other hand, your operation is not under your control or you are unable to add Refresh calls, then the next option available to you is to move your long operations into a thread.

### The "Old Way"

There are a couple of demo programs available for you to see how to do this. You basically put your work into a thread. When the thread is completed, it tells the GUI by sending a message through a queue. The event loop will run with a timer set to a value that represents how "responsive" you want your GUI to be to the work completing.

### The "New Way" - `Window.write_event_value`

This new function that is available currently only in the tkinter port as of July 2020 is exciting and represents the future way multi-threading will be handled in PySimpleGUI (or so is hoped).

Previously, a queue was used where your event loop would poll for incoming messages from a thread.

Now, threads can directly inject events into a Window so that it will show up in the `window.read()` calls. This allows a your event loop to "pend", waiting for normal window events as well as events being generated by threads.

You can see this new capability in action in this demo: Demo_Multithreaded_Write_Event_Value.py

Here is that program for your inspection and education. It's SO nice to no longer poll for threaded events.

```py
import threading
import time
import PySimpleGUI as sg

"""
    Threaded Demo - Uses Window.write_event_value communications

    Requires PySimpleGUI.py version 4.25.0 and later

    This is a really important demo  to understand if you're going to be using multithreading in PySimpleGUI.

    Older mechanisms for multi-threading in PySimpleGUI relied on polling of a queue. The management of a communications
    queue is now performed internally to PySimpleGUI.

    The importance of using the new window.write_event_value call cannot be emphasized enough.  It will hav a HUGE impact, in
    a positive way, on your code to move to this mechanism as your code will simply "pend" waiting for an event rather than polling.

    Copyright 2020 PySimpleGUI.org
"""

THREAD_EVENT = '-THREAD-'

cp = sg.cprint

def the_thread(window):
    """
    The thread that communicates with the application through the window's events.

    Once a second wakes and sends a new event and associated value to the window
    """
    i = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        window.write_event_value('-THREAD-', (threading.current_thread().name, i))      # Data sent is a tuple of thread name and counter
        cp('This is cheating from the thread', c='white on green')
        i += 1

def main():
    """
    The demo will display in the multiline info about the event and values dictionary as it is being
    returned from window.read()
    Every time "Start" is clicked a new thread is started
    Try clicking "Dummy" to see that the window is active while the thread stuff is happening in the background
    """

    layout = [  [sg.Text('Output Area - cprint\'s route to here', font='Any 15')],
                [sg.Multiline(size=(65,20), key='-ML-', autoscroll=True, reroute_stdout=True, write_only=True, reroute_cprint=True)],
                [sg.T('Input so you can see data in your dictionary')],
                [sg.Input(key='-IN-', size=(30,1))],
                [sg.B('Start A Thread'), sg.B('Dummy'), sg.Button('Exit')]  ]

    window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout, finalize=True)

    while True:             # Event Loop
        event, values = window.read()
        cp(event, values)
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
            break
        if event.startswith('Start'):
            threading.Thread(target=the_thread, args=(window,), daemon=True).start()
        if event == THREAD_EVENT:
            cp(f'Data from the thread ', colors='white on purple', end='')
            cp(f'{values[THREAD_EVENT]}', colors='white on red')
    window.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Multithreaded Programs

While on the topic of multiple threads, another demo was prepared that shows how you can run multiple threads in your program that all communicate with the event loop in order to display something in the GUI window. Recall that for PySimpleGUI (at least the tkinter port) you cannot make PySimpleGUI calls in threads other than the main program thread.

The key to these threaded programs is communication from the threads to your event loop. The mechanism chosen for these demonstrations uses the Python built-in queue module. The event loop polls these queues to see if something has been sent over from one of the threads to be displayed.

You'll find the demo that shows multiple threads communicating with a single GUI is called:

`Demo_Multithreaded_Queued.py`

Once again a warning is in order for plain PySimpleGUI (tkinter based) - your GUI must never run as anything but the main program thread and no threads can directly call PySimpleGUI calls.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is beyond my knowledge, I have tried to adapt threads into my code but can you at least tell me where should I make the function call? Thank you?

Comment: You can do your job in the thread function, `the_thread` here. Call `window.write_event_value` to generate event to `window` if you want to do something about the GUI, then handle this event in your event loop.